# How to create a rough green emerald material in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I would like to know how to create a rough looking green emerald in Cycles.

It should look like that, but can be even rougher and doesn't have to be that translucent. [image] 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this will help get you started.  You will still have a lot of work to do in order to refine the materials and lighting to get this to work.

[image]

Here's a link to the Fracture Modifier branch which was used to break up a model. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xiuirkoo0rac5tw/AAB2XQbs9K5uTIYcbDPUDW1Ca

[image]