# Problem: wrong coloring of reflection from glass-material after composing

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

I'm trying to make a 3D model that involves an emitting sphere within a cube made of glass. The material of the cube is just a mix of glass and diffuse shader and  it is on renderlayer 1. The render result of this layer looks quite ok, note especially the two small orange reflections on the cube surface which stem from the emitting sphere located on renderlayer 2:

Renderlayer 1:
*

Composed image:
[image]

When looking at the composed image you will notice, that as soon as the halo surrounding my sphere overlaps the two reflections on the cube surface, these reflections turn green. This doesn't look very nice and I just couldn't get rid of it.

Can anybody give me a hint how to fix this? Please keep in mind that I am very new to blender (this is actually the first model I've ever attempted). I hope I provided the most important pieces of information but please ask for any other parameters you might need. Of course, I can also upload the blender file. I use the cycles renderer.

Thanks for all your help in advance,
Felix

edit #1: node setup (first image removed due to restriction of number of links):
[image]

I already set the Clamp indirect value to 1 in order to reduce fireflies. When I increase Clamp direct to a value between 1 and 15, the green spots are gone, but so is the light emitting sphere. For value above 15 i get the green spots again.
Thanks for your answer! Felix

Comment: You will probably have to share your node setup screenshot if you want any meaningful answers. You might need some value clamping somewhere in your compositing setup

Comment: You may want to investigate [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40226/how-to-construct-a-diamond-or-other-gemstone-material-in-cycles/40836#40836)