# Rendering a set diamond in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have been trying to render a diamond. I successfully managed plain stones. But when try working on diamonds set in metal, the effect disappears.

Any suggestions?

[image: diamond material nodes in blender]

This is the image I get without metal.
[image]

Comment: I don't know about your material set-up, but usually jewelers keeps a hole in the metal behind the stones to let the light go through it and have nice reflexions/diffractions. If it's not the case with your model, maybe this little trick could improve your render ?

Comment: maybe you could show also the "successful" result to compare what are you missing now...

Comment: Hi, Yes. I have kept the holes. That's not the issue.

Comment: You need to work a bit more on your material, read this post:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40226/how-to-construct-a-diamond-or-other-gemstone-material-in-cycles . Also your lighting setup could help you bring out the qualities of the glass, Work on placing smaller light sources along with the larger ones in strategic places to reflect the complexity of the surfaces.

Answer (score 5):

Although you didn't specify what the "effect" is that's disappearing, I can tell from your node setup that the pseudo-refraction effect is only going to give you multi-colored noise:
[image]

This is because in real life, different wavelengths have different refraction indices.  When you change the IOR's on the different shaders and remove that extra ***Add Shader*** node, you can begin to see the colors:

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Also, if you're really interested in accurate light refraction, Cycles is not the engine you should be using.  For a free engine that can interface with Blender ***and*** accurately model caustics, look at Luxrender [ http://www.luxrender.net/en_GB/blender_2_5 ] which has unbiased rendering capability.  This is one I rendered with Luxrender:

[image]

EDIT 2: I think it depends more on your lighting than on the setting.  It will naturally be darker because of the shadows being cast, but you should still be able to get refraction shimmer.  I just added a simple, enclosed metal container and used the setup above:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. As mentioned earlier. Without the metal, my diamond looks good. But with the metal the sparkling crystalline effect disappears.

Comment: @SandipBharane - see edit to answer